# How is clan XP calculated?

Tags: clash-of-clans

They just added clan levels to CoC. XP is awarded for clan wars. How is the XP calculated for clan wars? (Looking for the mathematical formula)

Also, is there any strategies to boost awarded XP?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From what I have initially seen in my Clan's Current Wars you gain:

- +50 exp for winning the war
- +10 exp for 40% of stars gained
- +25 exp for 60% stars

and there seems to be a set amount of exp that's gained from attacks.

the [Wikia](http://clashofclans.wikia.com/wiki/Clans#Clan_XP) however explains this better

> Clan XP is a recent addition to the game; earning enough for the clan will level up the clan and unlock new things for the clan. It is earned through participation in Clan Wars. There are a few ways to earn Clan XP:
>
> - Defeat enemy War Bases: this will earn a small amount of XP. Note that only the first successful attack gives XP, after that the base doesn't give any more XP.
>
>   - Bases 1-5: 5 XP
>   - Bases 6-15: 4 XP
>   - Bases 16-25: 3 XP
>   - Bases 26-50: 2 XP
> - Accumulate enough Stars in the War: this earns more XP than simply defeating War Bases.
>
>   - Getting 40% of all stars: +10 XP
>   - Getting 60% of all stars: +25 XP
> - Win the War: This earns 50 Clan XP for the clan, which is a lot.

The XP for the 40% and 60% thresholds stack so if you get 60% of the stars you gain +35 XP

the maximum amount of XP a clan can gain in the war is shown in both the War Stats page and the War Results page however given what the wikia says the absolute maximum amount of XP a clan can gain from any one war is as follows<sup>*</sup>:

```
50     = Win
10     = Got 40% of stars
25     = Got 60% of stars
5 x 5  = first 5 bases in on the war map each giving 5 XP
10 x 4 = bases 6 - 15 on the war map each giving 4 XP
10 x 3 = bases 16 - 25 on the war map after each giving 3 XP
25 x 2 = the last 25 bases each giving 2 XP

                       25         40         30         50
Max = 50 + 25 + 10 + (5 x 5) + (10 x 4) + (10 x 3) + (25 x 2) 
Max = 50 + 25 + 10 + 25 + 40 + 30 + 50 

Max = 230 XP
```

---

<sup>*: value can be more during promotions such as the Double Clan XP</sup>